# Workflow: To be invoiced "if there´s 35 days between created date and actual date"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date

I´m looking for a workflow to achieve a field "To be invoiced" Yes or Not depending on the creation date and the actual date.

Creation date and actual date are calculated fields as for instance: 03/2017

I wanted to have a "yes" in the field to be invoiced if there´s 35 days between the creation date and actual date.

I don´t know if it´s possible.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this sample workflow...

[image: Sample Workflow]

I've checked this solution for 'minutes', so it should works for 'days'.
CreationDate is 'Date and Time' column.

You only start the workflow once on item. Workflow will leave the loop on the right day. If you want, you can use 'Send an Email' to let an employee know...

Comment: Thank you ver much for your help. I´m going to test it and I´ll keep you update ;)